# How do I format AWS account numbers in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to keep a bunch of AWS account numbers in Excel. However, the format is in scientific notation and doesn't show the complete number: 4.01E+11

The correct number is: 400723089300

But if I got to format cells -> custom and add 12 zeros (same number of digits in the account number), I get this, which is an incorrect account number: 400723000000

So how can I get the correct number to expand in excel?

Comment: format it as text.

Comment: If I do that, this is the result: 4.00723E+11
It's still in scientific notation.

Comment: The cell need to be formatted as text prior to putting in the value.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the cell format to **Number**:

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you! I don't have enough karma yet to vote you up, but I would in an instant if I could!

Answer (score 1):

Use, it is help when number start with Zero

#### Option 1

```
=RIGHT("000000000000"&A2, 12)
```

#### Option 2

```
1. Use More Number format
2. Custom format
3. In Type field write 000000000000, click on "Ok"
```